# About the etymology of Bachelor

Tags: etymology

I ran across this while I was browsing some Arab websites:

The Arabic Origin of ‘Baccalaureate’ and ‘Bachelor’
By: Abdul-Settar Abdul-Latif

> When Oxford and Cambridge Universities were erected as two cradles of
>   sublime learning, the scholastic masters at the time wondered as to
>   the title of the degree the two centres would bestow their graduates
>   maintaining the latter’s rights.
>
> Modern research points to the year
>   1167 as the date at which Oxford became a stadium generale (A place of
>   study). The research tells that studies at Oxford were suspended
>   nearly in 1209 and accordingly three thousand scholars dispersed, some
>   to Reading, some to Cambridge, some to Paris.
>
> By the end of the
>   twelfth century, Cambridge was to come a town of importance, but it is
>   not still early in the thirteenth century that genuine history records
>   the presence there of a concourse of clerks. In order to be out of
>   their bafflement, there was no harm, the masters believed, from
>   borrowing from the experiences of other peoples who had earlier
>   established their own institutes and centres of learning. Thus Oxford
>   and Cambridge masters tended their faces to the universities of the
>   Moslems’ Orient in order to check, and learn what degree the Islamic
>   universities awarded their graduates.
>
> The famous institute of learning
>   at the time was Al-Ma’moon’s Bait Al-Hikma (The House of Wisdom) which
>   later came to be known as Al-Mustensiriyah University in Abbassaid
>   Baghdad at the early decades of the ninth century. Bait Al-Hikma was
>   founded by Caliph Al-Ma’moon (Haroon Al-Rasheed’s second son) whose
>   tenure ranged from 813 to 833.
>
> The research testifies that Baghdad, as
>   a centre of learning, preceded both Oxford and Cambridge by at least
>   three or four hundred years in defining the prerequisites of learning
>   and education.  Also, the research proved that Ancient
>   Al-Mustensiriyah awarded any Moslem student that was graduated a
>   certain license legally, technically, and professionally covering him
>   to “restate what its holder had learnt in the university on the hand
>   of his referred-to Moslem scholars in order to re-teach others
>   elsewhere who could not afford to come to Baghdad to study, for one
>   reason or another”. This is the crux of what was written in the
>   license. But Arabic language is synoptic.
>
> In the license was written a
>   brief term annexed to the holder’s name. It honoured him the legal and
>   professional right to behave within the limits of its privileges. The
>   term can be literary transcribed into English as it is pronounced in
>   Arabic. It is “Bihaqq al-riwayatt” " بحق الرواية ". The term
>   incorporates three Arabic words: ‘Bi’ stands as preposition (with);
>   ‘haqq’ (the right) and “Al-riwayatt” (to restate the learning to
>   somebody else). That is to say ancient Moslem graduate was awarded
>   “with the right to restate the learning to somebody else”.
>
> And this is
>   the true meaning of “Bachelor” or “Baccalaureate” used in almost
>   European languages. Now the term with its preposition “Bihaqq
>   Al-riwayatt” later was taken as a title of the degree itself by
>   European scholars, students and translators who frequented the nearest
>   parts of the Ancient Islamic Empire to, Christendom; these parts were
>   Cordova, Toledo, Castello in Spain and Sicily in Italy as well as
>   Malta as the main Arab centres of learning and rendition at medieval
>   ages.
>
> “Bihaqq Al-riwayatt” thus was exposed to many alterations and
>   modification related to the different new linguistic region the term
>   reached and resided. The above mentioned variations of the term-
>   "Baccalaureate and Bachelor” are in use. This fact is unknown to many
>   people of well-established scholarship.
>
> For instance, The Random House
>   Dictionary of the English Language sets queer etymology for these two
>   variations. While (Bacca + laures), according to The Random, means
>   “laurel berry”, (Bachelor), again according to The Random, is taken
>   from a vulgar Latin word spelled as (baccalaris) that descends from
>   (bacca), itself a variation of a Latin word for (cow=vacca). One
>   wonders what the connection between (dairy farm) or (cows) and (a
>   university degree). The story of the trip the Arabic word took to
>   reach Europe was the topic of an article entitled “Did the Arab Invent
>   the University?” published in The Times Higher Education Supplement,
>   No. 185 (May 2, 1975), p. 11. by R. Y. Ebied & M. J. L. Young

Is this etymology plausible, or is it debunked?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is "Bihaqq al-riwayat" the real origin of Bachelor and Baccalaureate? Instead of copy-pasting, you could've posted that question plus a link to the site where you found this looong text (by the way, difficult to read, with peculiar grammar and some leaps in logic). Won't comment on the ethymology, but find it curious that the title universities confer in Hispanic countries is "licenciado": "the licenced one" i.e. receives a license to legally practice.

Comment: That's the meaning of _Doctor_; from Latin _doceo_ 'I teach', _doctor_ 'one who teaches', specifically one who is licensed to teach in a university. In the twelfth century Arabic was unknown in Europe, and Latin was the universal language of learning. There is no evidence that this, or any other, Arabic phrase ever reached the ears of any European university until centuries later; certainly there is no evidence whatsoever that early European universities (Paris, Bologna, Oxford) adopted an Arabic term for one of their degrees.

Comment: From "docere" also comes "docente", a very archaic and formal word for a teacher in Spanish. jlawler's right: outside Spain and other places in southern Europe under Muslim domination, nobody knew Arabic - so it was Jews usually who were tasked with translating Arabic texts.

Comment: OED says that the word *bachelor* (ME *bacheler*) originally meant "A young knight, not old enough, or having too few vassals, to display his own banner, and who therefore followed the banner of another; a novice in arms."

Comment: Le Grand Robert adds that OF *bacheler* (1080) was also used with the same meaning, cf. "Sous la féodalité, Jeune gentilhomme qui aspirait à devenir chevalier, et s'y préparait sous la conduite d'un seigneur."

Comment: @JoePineda Archaic? Interesting, it's regularly used in Italy. Not really in informal speech but still.

Comment: @Alennano yep, archaic. Nobody would call their teachers, from kindergarten up to post-grade "mi docente", only in very formal settings (e.g. a speech reference to "el cuerpo docente de la universidad" instead of "el profesorado universitario"). It's very used, though, in the news as replacement of "maestro" or "profesor" (due to this style rule of never using the same word twice in the same paragraph). Likewise, "docencia" or "magisterio" in reference to the teachers' guild in general, or a teachers' union in particular.

Comment: OED don't mention this Arabic etymology for bachelor/bacclaureate at all.

Comment: @JohnLawler Spain is not part of Europe?  Let's not forget them. The earliest studium generale in Spain was: Studium Generale de Palencia in 1208 (it would become the University of Salamanca in 1218). The origin of baccalaureate is Middle Latin, it is thought, meaning the one on whom laurels are bestowed. https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachiller

Comment: In the twelfth century Spain was not a part of Europe, no. It wasn't until a couple centuries later that it joined completely. For that matter, it wasn't until then that there **was** a "Spain". Up till then it was just a bunch of principalities, like the Germanies, only some of the principalities were Moslem.

Comment: @JohnLawler Most of Europe was not countries in 1200 either.  It was dominated by the Holy Roman Empire, with France, and a multitude of small kingdoms and states. The Kingdoms of Aragon and Castille had not yet become the Kingdom of Spain (1492). That said, Arabic until the Moors were kicked out of power left its mark. And all kinds of multi-lingual scholars gathered in places like Seville, Cordoba, Granada and Toledo. A lot came through Toledo, the first translators school in the world. At the time,  people flocked to Moorish Spain with its centers of learning.

Comment: To say something is the true meaning of something, is not to say that it is the translation of it. The text in poor English cited by the OP does not actually say that the Arabic meaning the writer ascribes to the term is actually the translation of the term. If one reads the excerpt carefully....[correx to previous post: were it not for..]

Comment: To say Spain was not "part of Europe" is slightly absurd in my view. In fact, were it for the Toledo School, ***European scholars would not have had access to Greek texts, and would have been limited to Latin. It was these people who brought classical Greek culture to Europe!*** or that land mass called Europe in geography.

Comment: http://ringmar.net/irhistorynew/index.php/introduction-3/the-arabs-in-spain/the-toledo-school-of-translators/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it has been debunked many times.  Here is one such case:
http://www.salaam.co.uk/knowledge/baccalaureate.php

Comment: Either your dictionary or your linking skills are at fault: that site tries to support the theory (though without any actual evidence). *Debunking* the idea would be to say,for example, "The word *bachelor* was used for a young knight long before the first Arabic university. The origin is not clear, but the progress from there to meaning 'scholar who has completed a course of study but is not ready to teach' is well-documented."

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be a fascinating read in support of the Arabic etymology:
http://www.jphogendijk.nl/arabsci/bachelor.html

Synopsis: there is no certain documentary evidence; there were early occidental/european scholars educated at arab institutions, and this is known because they left latin translations of arabic texts; there are historical arabic documents ("ijazat") using the term of art "bi-haqq al-riwaya;" the assonance is there.

While hardly definitive, it is better supported and cited than some other sources.